# Query on Vertical partitioning in Sybase

Tags: sql, partitioning, sap-ase

Am working with sybase.In that i have a table A of some 2 million records containing some columns which i want to move out and make it as a separate table B. I have some questions in this process...
1. I have decided to use vertical partitioning.Is that ok?
2.Or what other technique can i go about using in this process?

Please provide your valuable inputs in this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[Vertical partitioning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28database%29) *is* moving columns to a new table. So in *that* process you can not use any other technique (all 'other' techniques are the same thing with different wording).